# JavaScript function gets called multible times by event listener even though I reference the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, event-listener

I’m adding an event listener on each time I create an angular controller.  Each time I leave this page and come back to it, a new event listener gets added cause the constructor is called again.

When this event gets triggered, the same event gets invoked twice, and if I leave and come back, it gets invoked 3 times… etc.. I only want it to always get invoked once.

Here is the code to add the event listener, and the Listener function it calls:
(FYI I'm using TypeScript)

In Constructor:

```
this.$window.addEventListener("message", this.processApi, false);
```

Function Called:

```
processApi = (e) => {
    this.processApiMessage(e.data);
};
```

I read that I should call a reference to a function instead of typing out the function itself, so both reference the same instance of a function, but the same event listener is being called multiple times.

When I do developer tools in chrome, and go to EventListners, and go to message section, I see a new Window element every time I hit the constructor.  I am able to delete each of the EventListers through developer tools but can't seem to get it to work through code when I do:

```
this.$window.removeEventListener("message", this.processApi, false);
```

I found out that if I refresh the page, all the event listeners clear and my one in the constructor is created so it works fine.

I'm using angular, and was using the $location service to navigate to the url that hit my controller, so a quick fix was to replace $location.url("url") to window.location.href("url")

This seems to work cause the page gets refreshed when I navigate to it.  I would rather keep the $location for routing, and only have my event listener get hit once even though the angular constructor is hit multiple times.

Comment: That's the beauty of Angular, it messes everything up because it doesn't really redirect, it just changes "views". You probably want to set that event handler to `$rootScope` or remove the event handler on `$destroy` in the controller ?

Comment: Yeah, what is this constructor? Where is it called from?

Comment: The constructor is called within a route segment (when this, use this segment with this controller). I can try setting to to rootScope, but I'm adding it through window cause I'm communicating with another window through an IFrame using postApi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the event listener when the scope is `$destroyed`. So, in the controller constructor, you need to inject the `$scope` object. And in the constructor, do something like this:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', () => 
  $window.removeEventListener("message", this.processApi));
```

To be sure, there are several ways of creating a controller. The most common one (especially if you are using TypeScript) is to create a class for the controller.

I would also consider adding the listener to the rootScope instead of $window, which is more the Angular way of doing things. Putting it all together, it would look like this:

```
class MyController {
  constructor($rootScope, $scope) {
    'ngInject';

    let unsubscriber = $rootScope.$on('message', this.processApi, false);    
    $scope.$on('$destroy', () => unsubscriber());  
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to remove on destroy and it still isn't working.  I thought as long as I reference the same function, I wouldn't even need a remove, they would all point to the same function.  In the chrome debugger, under the event Listeners section, there is a message dropdown, each time I hit the constructor, a new Window is being added, which has a useCapture, passive, and handler property.  The handler property is the function(e), its like its being registered as a generic function instead of the reference name I gave it.

Comment: I would check to make sure that your $destroy event is being raised when you think it is. In the chrome debugger, set a breakpoint inside the $destroy handler. Is it being invoked when you think it should? What exactly is the code that you are using?

Comment: Ya that worked, thanks, I tried to do a bind(this) to another function name.  When I pasted your code in, I had mismatching names (this.processApi vs the new one I made when I did the add event listener).  Thanks again.